# What Meta Languages in 5 Years?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, alchemy

This is my first question so sorry if it's not worded great.

A lot of junior developers like myself have jumped into html/css/javascript, climbed the mountain of tailwindcss and tackled the solidity functions and implementations.

However like we all know, tech changes. New technologies are coming out every year and old languages are updating themselves to compete.

In your opinion what path would you suggest someone take if they were ONLY interested in developing on blockchain in ethereum?

Javascript, React, MongoDB, Solidity, Alchemy, and Git. Seem to be the meta play. Do you see this changing within the next 5 years and how so?

Answer (score 0):

> In your opinion what path would you suggest someone take if they were ONLY interested in developing on blockchain in ethereum?

If you work hard and continuously upgrade your skills, it won't matter. In five years you are probably going to master at least three programming language and learning a nea w one will take you couple of weeks. However if you are still coding only in JavaScript in five years your career is probably in a dead end.

It is all soft skills and domain specific knowledge that matter for senior developers

- General experience with a blockchain for five years, or so called domain specific knowledge
- People you know
- Companies where you can get into
- Your open-source Github track record and status as a star developer
- Your online reputation on forums like ethereum.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com
- Your appearance in conferences, offline and online